# Why doesn't recv block until it receives all of the data?

Tags: python, c, sockets, network-programming

Why doesn't the `recv` system call just block until all the data is received? Every time I have seen a `recv` call, it's in a while loop which just keeps on calling `recv` until all the data is there. Why not just have `recv` block in the first place?

Answer (score 9):

You can request that recv block until all data is received, with the `MSG_WAITALL` flag. However, if a signal arrives, a system call that has performed some work (ie, receiving part of the data) *cannot* be automatically restarted to receive the rest. As such, even with `MSG_WAITALL`, there are cases where the recv call may return before the buffer is full, and you must be prepared to handle these cases. Given this, many people simply choose to loop and not bother with little-known flags such as `MSG_WAITALL`.

As for why this is the case by default, there are a few reasons that come to mind:

- Frequently you *want* to receive partial reads. For example, if you're incrementally displaying the data as it comes in, or if you're proxying it to somewhere else, or if the data is just so large you can't buffer the whole thing in memory at once. After all, if you're just immediately writing to a file, do you care that you split it across 200 writes instead of, say, 150?
- Sometimes you don't even know how much data you need at the start. Consider the `telnet` protocol, which was popular around the time when the BSD sockets API was designed. You'll typically be receiving a handful of bytes at a time, there are no length fields telling you how much data to expect, and moreover you need to display that data *right away*. It doesn't make sense to block until you fill a buffer here. Likewise with line-oriented protocols such as SMTP or IMAP - you don't know how long the command is until you've received all of it.
- `recv` is often used for datagram sockets, where it receives a single datagram, even if it's much smaller than the buffer provided. The natural extension to streaming sockets is to just return as much as you can without waiting.

But most importantly, since you need to be prepared to deal with a partial buffer *anyway*, it's good to force people to deal with it by default, so they turn up the bugs in their loop early - rather than having them remain hiding until a signal arrives at an unfortunate moment.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, you don't know how much data is "all of the data". For example, if you're receiving data in a line-oriented protocol, a line might be 10 bytes long or 65 bytes long.

Answer (score 2):

You can change socket flags to either blocking or non-blocking. Your specific case actually has nothing to do with blocking or not blocking.

It would make no sense to make a network function behave in the way you describe by default - what if the stream never ends .. should the program never end? Prima facia, this doesn't seem like healthy *default* behavior.

Read http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/nonblocking.html to familiarize yourself with blocking and non-blocking IO.